# How to select a feature on WMS or Vector layer

Tags: gis, openlayers, layer, geoserver

I have a Vector layer set up on a WMS layer, on which I need to select features and highlight those on map, not by clicking on map but by clicking a button or something external to the map. Here is the code:

```
regioni = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "regioni",
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mmasgis/wms",
            {layers: 'mmasgis:reg2011_g', format: 'image/gif'}
);

select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", {styleMap:
            new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])
});

map.addLayers([regioni, select]);

selectionControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
            protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(regioni),
            box: true,
            hover: true,
            multipleKey: "shiftKey",
            toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });
        selectionControl.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
            select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        selectionControl.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
            select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
map.addControl(selectionControl);
selectionControl.activate();
```

With this code I can select features by clicking on map with no problems, but I need to select features by clicking on something external to my map. The main issue is that I have to pass a `OpenLayers.Feature` object to the selectionControl.addFeatures method, but I don't have that Object, but just the `fid` or some information contained in the WMS layer.

I'm working with Geoserver & Openlayers on tomcat7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same and I could not do it.
I am not sure that your selectionControl has addFeatures method/function.
In fact it does not have any methods at all:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/GetFeature-js.html

I think GetFeature control is a black box and we cannot add new selected features programmatically. You can modify the source code if you like.

I am going to do it this way:
- intercept onclick event
- get lon/lat from mouse's x and y
- use GetFeature function of WMS to get the features from the GeoServer
- add them to the select layer

I have not finished yet. The code sample to get feature by ID from WMS:

```
function preSelect(fID) {

    var processResponse = function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            console.log(resp.error);
            var data = resp.responseText;               
            var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
            var features = geojson_format.read(data,null,null);
            select.addFeatures(features);
    };

    OpenLayers.Request.issue({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '2.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'ESD:LLSOA',
            outputFormat:'json',
            featureID: fID,                             
        },
        callback: processResponse
    });
}
```

I think you can replace featureID by bbox parameter. Alternatively, WMS has similar GetFeatureInfo function which accepts x and y. In both cases coordinates must be in the same projection as your base layer.

Also, I had issues with accuracy of WFS GetFeature method. Same issue is explained here:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Problems-with-WFS-GetFeature-Bounding-Box-low-accuracy-td3799986.html